# All links in WP blog redirect to main non-WP site

Tags: installation, wp-redirect

I worked on a Drupal site for a client, but he wanted to keep his blog on WP, so I manually created a 'blog' folder on the root of the Drupal site and moved all the WP content there. I uploaded the database and change the wp-config.php settings accordingly.

The main Drupal site (example.com) works fine, and when I click on the blog link I'm taken to the front page of the blog like it's supposed to, but inside the blog, (example.com/blog), any other link I click will show a 'page not found' message as if I was looking for non existing content on the main site.

I'm not very familiar with WP. Is it because I installed manually? what configuration am I missing?

EDIT:

I tried

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com/blog/');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com/blog/');
```

on wp-config.php, but that didn't work.

Comment: For the URLs, once imported to your new site use wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-and-replace to fix the URLs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make a backup of your SQL database for the site and try running these queries manually on the database through php myadmin. change the URLs to match your site http://example.com/blog

As always, be careful when running queries on the database

```
 UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://www.oldurl', 'http://www.newurl') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

 UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://www.oldurl','http://www.newurl');

 UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://www.oldurl', 'http://www.newurl');

 UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'http://www.oldurl','http://www.newurl');
```

Answer (score 0):

There will not be trailing slash in your code.

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://example.com/blog' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com/blog' );
```

Although changing these values permanently in database is a good idea too.

Also visit your permalink settings page and save options again.